# How to set gallery starts from left corner?

Tags: android

I have one view ,view contains two buttons and one gallery. Gallery view pleased between two buttons . Now when I run the code. Gallery has default selected item is no 1 which is in center and left side is blank. Instead I want no 1 item should be at left and selected. for that i used following code,

```
MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) myGallery.getLayoutParams();
        mlp.setMargins(-100, mlp.topMargin, mlp.rightMargin,
                mlp.bottomMargin);
```

this is my adapter gallery_adapter.xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="180px"
        android:layout_height="169px" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/gallary_each_bg" 
        ></ImageView>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="80px"
        android:layout_height="80px" android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_marginTop="10px"></ImageView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="55px"
        android:textSize="20px" android:layout_marginTop="30px"></TextView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

this my main xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Gallery android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="350px" android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        ></Gallery>

    <Button android:layout_width="58px"
        android:id="@+id/prev" android:layout_height="114px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:background="@drawable/prevbutton"></Button>

    <Button android:layout_width="58px"
        android:id="@+id/next" android:layout_height="114px"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/nextbutton"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i didn't get any result.Some where i done mistake .please help me..

Answer (score -6, accepted):

That is easy just set gallery on another item:

> myGallery.setSelection(4);

Answer (score 8):

This is what you are [finding](http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-set-gallery-starts-from-left.html)

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

        // set gallery to left side
        MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) g.getLayoutParams();
        mlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels / 2 + (imageWidth/2)), mlp.topMargin,
                    mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
```

Comment: What is `imageWidth`?

Comment: imageWidth is your imageview of your row file.

Answer (score 0):

WindowManager wm=(WindowManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) Gallery.getLayoutParams();
  mlp.setMargins(-((metrics.widthPixels/2)+100), 
                 mlp.topMargin, 
                 mlp.rightMargin, 
                 mlp.bottomMargin